# bash locate command with pattern

Tags: bash, locate

I try to find a file with `locate` command.

It behaves itself some strange with patterns, at least not like `ls` or `find` commands.

I do the following:

```
sh@sh:~$ locate rhythmdb
/home/sh/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml
sh@sh:~$ locate "rhyth*"
sh@sh:~$ locate 'rhyth*'
sh@sh:~$ locate rhyth*
```

([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaQSU.png))

In my humble opinion it should find when asterisk is used too, but it doesn't.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `man locate`:

```
If  --regex is not specified, PATTERNs can contain globbing characters. If any
PATTERN contains no globbing characters, locate  behaves  as  if the pattern
were \*PATTERN*.
```

Hence, when you issue

```
locate rhyth*
```

`locate` will not find it, because there are no files that match this pattern: since there's a glob character, locate will really try to match (in regex): `^rhyth.*` and there are obviously no such matches (on full paths).

In your case, you could try:

```
locate "/home/sh/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhyth*"
```

or

```
locate '/rhyth' # equivalent to locate '*/rhyth*'
```

But that's not very good, is it?

Now, look at the first option in `man locate`:

```
   -b, --basename
          Match  only  the base name against the specified patterns.  This
          is the opposite of --wholename.
```

Hurray! the line:

```
locate -b "rhyth*"
```

should work as you want it to: locate a file with *basename* matching (in regex): `^rhyth.*`

Hope this helps.

**Edit.** To answer your comment: if you want to `locate` all *jpg* files in folder `/home/sh/music/`, this should do:

```
locate '/home/sh/music/*.jpg'
```

(no `-b` here, it wouldn't work). Notice that this will show all *jpg* files that are in folder `/home/sh/music` *and also* in its subfolders. You could be tempted to use the `-i` flag (ignore case) so that you'll *also* find those that have the uppercase *JPG* extension:

```
locate -i '/home/sh/music/*.jpg'
```

**Edit 2.** Better to say it somewhere: the `locate` command works with a database — that's why it can be much faster than `find`. If you have recent files, they won't be `locate`d and if you delete some files, they might still be `locate`d. If you're in this case (which might be the purpose of your other comment), you must update `locate`'s database: *as root*, issue:

```
updatedb
```

*Warning.* The command `updatedb` might take a few minutes to complete, don't worry.

Comment: I hate to set one more silly question, but is it possible to specify certain location?  e.g. I tried to do: locate -b "/home/sh/music/*.jpg", but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @gekannt You don't need the `-b` flag in this case.

Comment: ok, I tried  it doesn't work, if I do find . *.jpg, I  get many files, if I do locate - nothing. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18776391/storage/21%3A22%3A1323062013_001.png   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18776391/storage/21%3A25%3A5723062013_001.png   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18776391/storage/21%3A28%3A3423062013_001.png

Comment: If these are recent files, you might need to update `locate`'s database: issue _as root_ the command `updatedb` (it might take a few minutes to perform, don't worry).